# Fastest way to generate two random numbers from the same range

Tags: java, performance, random

I've been making a little game in Java and I'm using the Java Random class to generate random number.

During the course of the game, two teams play one another, and to figure out who wins the match, I generate two random numbers (from 1 to 10, like a d10) and then do some modifications to those scores, comparing them to find out who wins.

But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it. I don't really know exactly how the Java Random class works, but my idea was that I would instead generate a single random number (from 1 to 100) and then integer divide by 10 to get one of the numbers and then do mod 10 to find the other number.

In code, my question is which of these is faster:

```java
Random r = new Random();
int team1Score;
int team2Score;
int randNum;

// current version
team1Score = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
team2Score = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

// new version
randNum = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
team1Score = randNum / 10;
team2Score = randNum % 10;
```

And if, anyone has any ideas, is there any way to make it even more efficient than either of these?

Comment: Why not benchmark both ways and compare the timings? If the pseudo random generator is costly, the second approach will be more efficient but probably not by much. Test and let the clock be the judge.

Comment: I'll also point out that the attempt to optimize created a bug: your second version shouldn't add 1 to r.nextInt(100), it needs to add 1 to team1score and team2score to give the range 1-10 with uniform probability. This isn't to discourage experimenting with optimizations, just that hand-rolling custom random distributions is an extremely common source of bugs.

Comment: Good point, yeah, that'll mess up the integer division one. After this experience, I'll make sure that I go through all my custom random distributions to find any bugs like this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). The difference between these two examples is incredibly small, and you really shouldn't worry about it. I'd go with the first for the sake of readability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Because I have to simulate hundreds of thousands of these matches at a time, I just wanted to make sure it was as quick as possible.

Comment: @riggsmarkham in that case, you may want to consider asking another question about optimizing *that* -  there may be a clever way to reuse values or batch the calculations.

Comment: The whole match algorithm is a much bigger beast, so I'll likely go through it all myself once again in order to try and optimize it. But, thank you, I'll might post it all on here for suggestions after this!